# How to show "properties window" of native file system's file/folder in java

Tags: java, windows, linux, macos, file-properties

I am using java 1.6 and my java desktop application run on three O.S Windows, Linux and MAC. Using my application, user can list files and folder of native file system in `JTree`.

My requirement is user can able view a "property window" of file/folder according to native file system. Suppose if user in running my java desktop application on Window then if user right click on any file/folder and select "Properties" then this window can open -

[image]

If in-case we can not show native file system's file/folder properties file using java 1.6 then is there any way to get all these file/folder properties?

Comment: For Windows you can use ShellExecute with "properties" verb.

Comment: Does this answer your question [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39490893/1866870](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39490893/1866870) ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a how to:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html