# Open a file's properties window using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, properties

This is a question only regarding Java in Windows.

I need a method that will call this window:

[image]

So essentially the method should be something like:

```
public void openProperties(File file){ // or String fileName

}
```

So the statement: `opernProperties(new File(test.txt));` should open the above window.

So just to clarify, I do not want to read and manage the properties. I just want to open the properties window.

Comment: This question was already asked without an answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132939/how-to-show-properties-window-of-native-file-systems-file-folder-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132939/how-to-show-properties-window-of-native-file-systems-file-folder-in-java)

Comment: I think your best option is to use  [java native access](https://github.com/java-native-access) and than try to use the following code [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33472984/1866870](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33472984/1866870)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to display the file properties window using the following:

- Go to https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/
- Download the snapshot JARs jna-4.3.0-20160510.203907-1.jar and jna-platform-4.3.0-20160510.204004-1.jar (We can't use the latest version that is located at maven repo since it's 4.2.2 and it does not have the SHELLEXECUTEINFO)
- Load the jars and paste the following code below

This should display the properties window with a delay of 3 seconds. Notice that alk talked about passing the window through hwnd member if you don't want it to auto close after the 3 seconds

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ShellAPI.SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExecuteInfo = new ShellAPI.SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
        shellExecuteInfo.lpFile = "C:\\setup.log";
        shellExecuteInfo.nShow = User32.SW_SHOW;
        shellExecuteInfo.fMask = 0x0000000C;
        shellExecuteInfo.lpVerb = "properties";
        if (Shell32.INSTANCE.ShellExecuteEx(shellExecuteInfo)){
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's just for the example, so you'd be able to to see the window.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API call [SHObjectProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shobjectproperties) will also launch Windows file property dialog. You could call from JNA, JNI or try JDK Panama / Foreign Memory API available as incubator in JDK16 or above.

Foreign Memory API is part of JDK22 so the following code will launch the Properties dialog in Windows in JDK22:

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws Throwable {

    try(Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined())  {

        // NOTE: must use absolute path
        Path path= Path.of(args[0]).toAbsolutePath();

        // Java String to Windows Wide String:
        MemorySegment pszObjectName = arena.allocateFrom(path.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);

        // Invoke Windows API
        int hres = Native_h.SHObjectProperties(MemorySegment.NULL, Native_h.SHOP_FILEPATH(), pszObjectName, MemorySegment.NULL);
        System.out.println("SHObjectProperties path="+path +" hres="+hres);
    }

    // Properties dialogs will close when the this app exits
    System.out.println("Press any key to exit");
    System.in.read();
}
```

The source code for for native call bindings can be generated by using `jextract` commands:

```
echo #include ^<shlobj_core.h^> > Native.h
jextract -lshell32 -t some.name --output generated --include-function SHObjectProperties --include-constant SHOP_FILEPATH Native.h
```

The above command would generate the Java calls needed to access native methods, or this is the equivalent definition hand-crafted in Java:

```
class Native_h {
    private static final SymbolLookup SHELL32 = SymbolLookup.libraryLookup("shell32", Arena.global());

    // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shobjectproperties
    private static final MethodHandle SHObjectProperties = Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
        SHELL32.find("SHObjectProperties").get(),
        FunctionDescriptor.of(JAVA_INT, ADDRESS, JAVA_INT, ADDRESS, ADDRESS)
    );

    // invoke "SHObjectProperties"
    static int SHObjectProperties(MemorySegment hWnd, int shopObjectType, MemorySegment pszObjectName, MemorySegment pszPropertyPage) throws Throwable {
        return (int)SHObjectProperties.invokeExact(hWnd, shopObjectType, pszObjectName, pszPropertyPage);
    }
    // Constant needed for Properties
    static final int SHOP_FILEPATH() {
        return (int)2L;
    }
}
```